# How to display lead descripition field in vf page using javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, leads

I need to display lead description field in a vf page using javascript.
Coding :

```
var a = '{Lead.Description}';
alert(a);
```

The value is not coming . In console i am able to see one error "unterminated literal string".

The description i gave is :
                this is a
lead

Please provide a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You have to put ! before Lead

```
var a = '{!JSENCODE(Lead.Description)}';
alert(a);
```

It will show in the alert as Single Line but if you grab it to the VF Page, The Styles will be in same manner...

Hope this might helps...

Comment: ya tried this only !! dint work subhash

Comment: I put the same 2 line code in Custom button and checked within the Lead Object and It is working fine for me... Is that showing any error?

Comment: No subhash !! jus give the description like " This is " and then press enter and then type " a lead". and save the record. Now check.
I am saying that it is not accepting the line break

Comment: See my answer now... It will work for sure..

Comment: yes subhash tried this too !! when i use this , i am getting unterminated string literal error in console log

Comment: I think you didn't close the the var string correctly... the answer is working fine for me when I used in my lead object with ur scenario. What Input are u using exactly?

Comment: it worked !! thanks subhash !! prob was i didnt properly comment one line in my code.. thanx a lot

Comment: You're welcome and nice to hear that it worked...:)